# How to find mime type of a file in mobile application using angular 2 and ionic 2

Tags: angular, ionic2, ionic3

I am trying to upload a files from my application to server using https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/file-transfer/

It is mandatory to set Mime-Type in options of `upload(fileUrl, url, options, trustAllHosts)`

Currently i have the entire file path like `file://..../../abc.JPG` . My question is how can i find Mime-Type of a file from file name or file extension(which is in string format).

Answer (score 0):

Using the Ionic plugins Native :

- [File](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/file/) plugin

You should use the plugins 'getFile()' method to read its metadata